# Autoconvert `_id` to `ObjectID`

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there a way to tell the native MongoDB driver for NodeJS to automatically convert the contents of an `_id` field into an ObjectID?

Say, in this situation:

```
db.collection("collection").updateOne({_id: data._id}, data)
```

It's not that `data._id = ObjectID(data.id)` is hard, but it's another thing to miss each and every time.

Comment: Why do you need to use "native MongoDB"? What about mongoose?

Comment: AFAIK, mongoose is only somewhat isomorphic. I need something that DGAF if it's on the server or the browser; something with completely identical code between the two situations.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that natively. You can make some function for wrapping your mongo queries where you will check params and if it's "_id" parse it to ObjectId.